# Allow partial update in serializer_class in Django REST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios, partial, serialization

I am trying to partially update my ProfileSerializer when i am making PATCH request. However i am not able to make it beacuse by default Serializer doesn't allow partial changes to be made. I am using Django Rest Framwork UpdateModelMixin to handle my patch request. Where can i set `partial=True` in my case?

View:

```
class ProfileViewPartialUpdate(GenericAPIView, UpdateModelMixin):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'token'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'pk'

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Serializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('token', 'bio', 'name', 'email', 'sport', 'location', 'image')
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"doesn't allow partial changes to be made"*? Have you got any errors? What was the response? Moreover, If you are making a ***HTTP PATCH*** request, DRF will automatically set `partial=True`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu My error is PATCH 404 Bad Request

Comment: `404` status code indicates that you have *referenced an entity which does not exist in your database*

Comment: Sorry 400 Bad Request

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Is there anything else that can be wrong?

Comment: What was the *response*?

Comment: 400 Bad Request, but my urls and everything else is figured correctly

Comment: For example usual PUT works, but PATCH not

Comment: DRF will send back some information as *response*, check it out and you'll figure out what is the issue

Comment: Have you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63518660/12578202), seems it will work for you

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, this is only error Bad Request: /api/profile/e84d9f484e75eab046************/updatepartial, and it should be caused by partial being False. It could work correctly when i set partial=True

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, still getting bad request 400 error, it should be something with partial

Comment: Try the answer suggested by xxnora below. It will work.

Comment: @NeoYumnam, I tried, it didn't work. Bad request again

Answer (score 0):

Look at this snippet code from one of my projects. You can modify accordingly. Add this to ProfileViewPartialUpdate class instead of patch.

```
def partial_update(self, request, slug):
    user = self.request.user
    get_blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)

    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = BlogSerializer(instance, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(data="wrong parameters", status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Hope this might help

Comment: The thing is that, you don't have to set `partial=True` in *normal cases*, ie,  when you are using the built-in views *as-is*. The OP doesn't have any *customization*, yet

Comment: Yup, partial=True is not neccessary. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
from rest_framework import generics

class ProfileViewPartialUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

Serializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('token', 'bio', 'name', 'email', 'sport', 'location', 'image')
```